# List all of my categories with their ID

Tags: magento-1.9, custom

I need to get all of the `IDs` with the `category-name` in my website like:

> Shoes - ID:448
>
> Hats - ID:233

Is it in the database? `Sql queries` that I can use?

Comment: No need to use database query. It can be done from files. Where you want to display ID of category ?

Comment: In a .txt for example, I don't want to show it on my website, I just need a list of all the categories with their respective ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new file in your magento root directory and paste the following

```
<?php

define('MAGENTO', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once MAGENTO . '/app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$rootCatId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();

function getTreeCategories($parentId, $isChild) {
    $allCats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', '1')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu', '1')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', array('eq' => $parentId));

    $class = ($isChild) ? "sub-cat-list" : "cat-list";
    $html .= '<ul style="list-style:none;" class="' . $class . '">';
    foreach ($allCats as $category) {
        $html .= '<li>' . $category->getId() . ' - ' . iconv(mb_detect_encoding($category->getName(), mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $category->getName()) . "";
        $subcats = $category->getChildren();
        if ($subcats != '') {
            $html .= getTreeCategories($category->getId(), true);
        }
        $html .= '</li>';
    }
    $html .= '</ul>';
    return $html;
}

$catlistHtml = getTreeCategories($rootCatId, false);

echo $catlistHtml;
?>
```

then go to your http://www.yoursite.com/filename.php

this will give you the categories and the ids in tree format

Comment: Hello Dava, it worked as the way I wanted to, thanks! The only thing bothering me, is it possible to encode the string to utf-8? Some characters are missing. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated my answer to include utf-8 encoding on the category names

Comment: It doesn't work, I still see weird characters http://cuylas.com/categoriesambid.php

Comment: link doesnt work if you can copy and paste what you see may be able to provide a solution

Comment: Fixed it by myself, it was ISO-8859-1! Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't include all store views.

Answer (score 1):

Below Code will give you file in root Dir

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');
$myfile = fopen("a.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$catTree = $category->getTreeModel()->load();
$catIds = $catTree->getCollection()->getAllIds();
$cats = array();
if ($catIds){
     foreach ($catIds as $id)
     {
        $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
        $cat->load($id);
        fwrite($myfile, $cat->getName()." - ".$id."\n");
      }
} 
fclose($myfile);
exit;
```